# WSL --- Where did the SSH go?

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I even reinstalled WSL and still have this problem:

In a test environment, I've only one user (root) and when I go to `/root/` I have no ssh dir. It seems I can't use any SSH services as well, like tunneling to a server.

`apt-get install openssh-client` outputs that the software is already installed, but, it seems it isn't.

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: What errors you get?

Comment: There are no errors anywhere besides when I try to use SSH to tunnel to an SSH. The error is ``Resource temporarily unavailable``. Answers talk bout making an exception to Bash in third party Antivirus or configuring something in the ``/ssh</code`` but this is exactly the directory that I don't have, for some reason.

Comment: It will probably not be `/root/ssh`, but in `/ssh`

Comment: Sadly I don't have a dir ```/ssh/```...

Comment: Look in `/etc/ssh/`?

Comment: Yes it was there. There are 3 files there, moduli, ssh_config, and ssh_import_id... Anyway, now I will try fix the error I putted in the comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### I have no ssh dir. It seems I can't use any SSH services as well.

In WSL the `ssh` directory is located in `/etc/ssh`